# Pig UDF that accept multiple inputs

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Quick q on Pig UDFs.

I have a custom UDF that I want to accept multiple columns:

```
package pigfuncs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.FuncSpec;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

public class DataToXML extends EvalFunc<String> {


      public DataToXML() {

      }

      @Override
      public List<FuncSpec> getArgToFuncMapping()
          throws FrontendException {
        List<FuncSpec> funcList = new ArrayList<FuncSpec>();
        funcList.add(new FuncSpec(this.getClass().getName(),
            new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, DataType.CHARARRAY))));

        return funcList;
      }

      @Override
      public String exec(Tuple t) throws IOException {


        if (t == null || t.size() == 0)
          return "";


        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        result.append("<Num>");
        result.append((String) t.get(0));
        result.append("</Num>");

        result.append("<Tags>");
        result.append((String) t.get(1));
        result.append("</Tags");


        return result.toString();
      }

}
```

I want to pass 2 columns; Number and Data.  I want the output to be XYZabc

I can't work out how to get the pig script to call this, every combination results in a different error!

An excerpt from my script:

```
-- apply some sort of UDF that returns the exact line without the stop words
nostop = FOREACH cleansed GENERATE lotnum,pigfuncs.StopWords(description) as data;

-- put into xml
out = FOREACH nostop GENERATE pigfuncs.DataToXML(lotnum, data);
```

The error from this is:

Could not infer the matching function for rapp.pigfuncs.DataToXML as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Hope this is an easy one for the Pig gurus :)

Duncan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getArgToFuncMapping()` implementation indicates you are only expecting one argument. (You have only added one field to `funcList`.)  If you're not going to be providing multiple implementations for this UDF depending on the types of the arguments, there's no real need to implement `getArgToFuncMapping()`.  Just skip it and this error will go away.